# Sound issues after upgrading to 23.04

Tags: sound, alsa, pipewire

I have a HP laptop, Omen 15, I used the previous ubuntu version with no issues, but I just upgraded and noticed a weird issue.

When I play a sound that has pauses in it, the sound cuts at the start of a new sound. It's hard to explain, but for example when I use the system sound test, I'm suposed to hear "Front Left" and I hear something like "nt left".

So listening to music, for example, it goes fine as long as the music has no full pause and quick resume.

I also have a bluetooth headset, and the sound works fine there. Only in the main laptop sound there's this issue.

I tried searching the web and can't seem to find a similar problem.

My audio devices screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

This is the audios I got. The Device-2 is the hdmi screen, but that screen has not audio built-in. So the problem is with the device-1.

Anyone facing the same issue, or has seen and could point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I have also began to come across this issue; not sure what's causing it, but +1...

Answer (score 0):

Go back to pulse.  The issue is the driver can operate in either interrupt or timer mode, but the hda driver does not work in timer mode well, so interrupt mode is necessary.  This is supported in pulse, still experimental and not documented in pipewire.

Comment: I found that pulse was part of the issue, in a way. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same or similar audio glitches. I also had some stuttering: "Bre-bread loaves." This was after I installed Audio Recorder. This program defaults to running at startup, and it seems that it starts pulse, even if pulse is already running. Change its settings so it doesn't run at startup. Then check:

```
ps -e | grep audio

1760 ?        00:00:00 pulseaudio
2241 ?        00:25:36 pulseaudio
```

You need only one. There can be only one. Kill one of them. That is what I did and the audio glitches went away.

I do not know if this is the answer for you, but it was my answer.

By the way, I have two audio devices, "Trinity HDMI Audio Controller" and "FCH Azalia Controller" but only one is hooked up to the stereo amplifier and massive speakers that I have. I don't know how you got your audio screenshot, but the "wireless" in the output looks like that might be for the Bluetooth, which you say is working fine. Try running:

```
sudo lshw -class multimedia
```

Comment: I might have to take this all back. I eliminated the sound issue for a while, but I use both vlc and firefox, each of which play sound, and they don't get along. I was watching something on vlc, after playing some music on youtube, and noticed the glitch again. There were two pulseaudio processes running. I killed one and I had no sound at all! I killed the wrong one, I guess. I don't understand why all these programs can't get along...